# Cerrar una conexión WebSocket en Angular

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

Tengo un componente en Angular, que en su constructor, se subscribe a un Websocket.
El problema es que cuando salgo de ese componente, queda subscripto. Quiero que al destruirse el componente, a su vez, se cierre la conexión del Websocket.

Este es mi código:

```
export class OrderService implements OnDestroy {
  public orders: Subject<Order[]>;

  constructor(private wscService: WebSocketService) {
    this.orders = <Subject<Order[]>>(
      wscService.connect(rutas.websocket.orders).pipe( map((response: MessageEvent): Order[] => {
        return JSON.parse(response.data)
      }))
    );
  }
}
```

En este servicio, como expliqué antes, se conecta al WebSocket.

---

El websocket service es

```
export class WebSocketService {
  constructor() { }

  private subject!: Rj.Subject<MessageEvent>;

  public connect(url:string): Rj.Subject<MessageEvent> {
    if (!this.subject) {
      this.subject = this.create(url);
      console.log('Successfully connected To: ' + url);
    }
    return this.subject;
  }

  private create(url:string): Rj.Subject<MessageEvent> {
    let wsc = new WebSocket(url);
    let observable = Rj.Observable.create((obs: Rj.Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
      wsc.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
      wsc.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
      wsc.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);
      return wsc.close.bind(wsc);
    });

    let observer = {
      next: (data: Object) => {
        if (wsc.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
          wsc.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
      },
    };

    return Rj.Subject.create(observer, observable);
  }
}
```

---

Obviamente quise crear un método en `WebSocketService` que sea `close()`, intentando desuscribirme del Subject para no recibir más nada, pero esto no me funciona, me siguen llegando datos.

```
public close(){
 this.subject.unsubscribe();
}
```

Ejecutandose cuando se destruye el componente `OrderService`:

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {    
  this.wscService.close();
}
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**
Me dí cuenta que el metodo `OnDestroy` del `OrderService`, no llega a ejecutarse. Por lo tanto, nunca llego al close() del WebSocket.

También probé en todas las capas desuscribirme, es decir, cree un metodo `close()` en el `OrderService` y en la capa donde recibo los datos. Todos iguales al metodo `close()` que está arriba: Tomando el Observable o Subject y aplicando el `unsubscribe()`

Es la primera vez que trabajo con WebSocket.
Informo por las dudas de que haya algo mal hecho en la conexión y deba cambiar las cosas desde ahí.

Answer (score 0):

lo que utilizo yo para desuscribirme es otro subscribe y el `pipe(takeUntil(...))`

#### Explicación de takeUntil

Básicamente, se desuscribe cuando otro subscribe recibe una llamada

Aquí te dejo algo de documentación del `takeUntil` https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/takeUntil

#### Ejemplo

```js
  _unSub = new Subject<boolean>();

  subscribeCualquiera.pipe(takeUntil(this._unSub).subscribe(....)

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this._unSub.next(true);
  }
```

En cuanto al `ngOnDestroy`. No funciona en los servicios porque no se "instancia", de forma sencilla es como decir que se instancian al iniciar la aplicación y no un componente.